# Cannot Keep Ubuntu Server running on a laptop despite workarounds

Tags: 14.04, server, laptop, suspend, power-management

I have Ubuntu 14.04.01 server.

I edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`and changed a line to

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Then I saved the file and executed `sudo restart systemd-logind`.
I even rebooted the computer and verified that `HandleLidSwitch` still has the correct value even after 2 reboots.

However, Ubuntu still sleeps when the lid is shut.

How can I disable sleeping on closing the lid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turned out the entire section was commented out I didn't realize because I am only use to commenting in C.

Answer (score 0):

Comment away *both* the `HandleLidSwitch` and `LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited` in `logind.conf` and then type: (In a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo restart systemd-logind
```

Then type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor false
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'nothing'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
```

and then report back here.